# Why datepicker is not working on 2 textboxes on the same page

Tags: javascript

```
$(function() {
  $("#date1 , #date2").datepicker({
    readonly_element: false,
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
  });
});
```

Comment: Please describe what's your problem?

Comment: If you have multiple element use class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

you should be using a **class** instead of **id** if you want to use datepicker for more than one textbox, like this -

```
$(function() {
  $(".date").datepicker();
});
```

and use it on the two textbox -

```
<input type="text" name="textboxt1" class="date">
<input type="text" name="textboxt2" class="date">
```

**Note** - this approach will help you to get datepicker to any number of textbox without assigning different ID's to each textbox, by using the same class on each of them.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/wjkywh2b/)

Comment: than post the html of textboxes where your are applying the datepicker..

Comment: also check your console for errors..open page in browser-> right click->inspect element-> console_window

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dave17/squ5p6ak/

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: can you add jquery-ui.js file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('.datetxt').datepicker({
        readonly_element: false,
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
    });
    $('#datepicker_example1').Zebra_DatePicker({
        readonly_element: false,
        format: 'd-m-Y'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using two different datepicker plugin or what ?